# TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` or `processAsync` function

Tags: typescript, jestjs

After updating jest to 27.0.6 version, running npm test results in the following error

```
 jest --config jest.config.js

 TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` or  `processAsync` function.
```

Package versions:

```
"jest": "^27.0.6",
"ts-jest": "^27.0.0",
```

jest config

```
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js?|tsx?)$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(scss?|css?)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
  },
  testRegex: '__tests__.*test.(ts|tsx)$',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/',

  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
  modulePaths: ['src'],

  // This fixed an error related to the CSS and loading gif breaking
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.(styl|css|scss)': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga|styl|css)$':
      '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
  },

  // mapCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/coverage',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['**/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}', '!**/loader.{ts,tsx}', '!**/node_modules/**'],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['.*\\.d\\.ts'],
  globals: {
    __DEV__: false,
    __TEST__: true,
    IS_NOT_SPA: false,
  },
};
```

Any pointers to resolve this issue would be helpful.

**UPDATE**

I resolved this problem

In setting i use transform like

```
module.exports = 'test-file-stub'
```

and I changed this to

```
module.exports = {
      process(src, filename, config, options) {
        return "module.exports = 'test-file-stub'";
      },
    };
```

you can see https://jestjs.io/docs/next/code-transformation

Comment: show you your jest config

Comment: you have cleared the cache ? it's a known issue.

Comment: yea, I tried, without success

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, i get it work by updating jest to **^27.2.1**. don't forget to clear the cache first.

Comment: yea, I just to try to update jest to 27.2.1 and clear the cache (jest --clearCache 
) but  without success

Comment: @ВадимБаранов have you also upgrade jest-cli ?

Comment: yea, have 27.3.1 version